# When we receive mms here I get address of sender but How to get location at MMBOX of our mmsc where the content is situated?

Tags: android, mms

Please check this code for Receive the MMS.

```
PduParser parser = new PduParser();
                PduHeaders headers = parser.parseHeaders(intent.getByteArrayExtra("data"));
                if (headers == null) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't parse headers for WAP PUSH.");
                  return;
                }
                int messageType = headers.getMessageType();
                if (messageType == PduHeaders.MESSAGE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION_IND) {
                    String fromStr = null;
                    EncodedStringValue encodedFrom = headers.getFrom();
                    if (encodedFrom != null) {
                      fromStr = encodedFrom.getString();
                      Log.d(TAG,"From str"+fromStr);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See how the stock does it here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.7_r1/com/android/mms/transaction/PushReceiver.java#104

The relevant part is:

```
case MESSAGE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION_IND: {
                    NotificationInd nInd = (NotificationInd) pdu;

                    if (MmsConfig.getTransIdEnabled()) {
                        byte [] contentLocation = nInd.getContentLocation();
```

Hope this helps...